# check if <ul> <li> has an active link?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

i have

```
<ul>
<li class="section-title">HEADER which triggers dropdown</li>
   <li><a href="element_one">element one</a></li>
   <li><a href="element_one">element one</a></li>
   <li><a href="element_one">element one</a></li>
</ul>
```

i'm hiding all li-elements (except the first one) with this line:

```
$('#menu ul li.section-title:first-child').parent().children('li').hide();
```

i wonder if it's possible to query if one of those three links is active and if so nothing should hide!

is that even possible? thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your code will actually hide all `li`
   elements (*including the first
   one*).
   Use `$('#menu ul li:not(:first-child)').hide();` to hide all but the first one..
2. For the next part (*to only hide them if none is the current one*) use

   ```
   var loc = window.location.href;
   var anyActive = false;
   $('#menu li a').each(function(){
       anyActive = anyActive || (this.href == loc);
   });

   if (!anyActive)
       $('#menu ul li:not(:first-child)').hide();
   ```

**Update with working code, after comment**

```
var loc = window.location.href;

$('#menu li a').each(function(){
    if (this.href == loc)
        $(this).addClass('activelink');
});

$('#menu ul:not(:has(.activelink)) li:not(:first-child)').hide();
```

live example: http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/SMmtS/21/

Comment: thank you, the only problem is that anyActive returns true if a link is active. however i have a few of those ul-navigatin elements side by side and only the one with the active link in it should show, not all of them!

Answer (score 0):

Why not attach a class to the active link, then you could do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() { $(".myClass").doSomething();});
```

Comment: if i click a link the page gets refreshed! if i attach a class when i click a link (so it's the active link) the page gets refreshed and the class is gone!

Comment: That's a server side question, really. Although you could try to deduce the clicked link from the url ... however, that's a rather foolish thing to do, it's much easier to just output a class server-side. If you are at all in control of the output, that is.

Comment: maybe i could write a cookie somehow and query what link got clicked last? i know theres a jquery cookie plugin! i just wondered if it's possible to query if a link is active!?!

Comment: Do it server-side as Fake51 said. Creating a cookie to track a link is a bit much.