# jQuery hover toggleclass issue

Tags: jquery, hover

i have some code that works perfect for my hover states. However, if the link is already active, i.e ArrowHover is already attached to the div when i hover over it obviously it removes ArrowHover due to the toggleclass in the jquery. How can i make sure this doesn't happen on links already active?

```
$("#JobApplications").hover(function()
    {
         $("#JobApplicationsArrow.Arrow").toggleClass('ArrowHover')
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it using css techniques instead of jQuery. Cheers anyways Adam!

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if we could see your HTML object, to know if it is an anchor tag or not... but assuming it is an anchor tag, try something along with this concept:

```
if ( $("#JobApplicationsArrow.Arrow").href != window.location.href ) {
    $("#JobApplicationsArrow.Arrow").toggleClass('ArrowHover')
}
```

It is a modified version from **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153229/check-if-ul-li-has-an-active-link)** post:

Comment: At the moment it's not an anchor tag, its an id for styling. I'm going to recode it to use classes more as i have id's all over the place haha

Comment: so is your object just a div with clickable text?